# Edit windows Group Policy from Command line (CMD)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I want to add some group policy and I need to added by batch file
How can I edit windows Group Policy from windows command line?

Answer (score 1):

Try **importregpol.exe**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2008/05/07/lgpo-utilities.aspx

It will import whatever is in the pol file you specify. To make a pol file I blank the policy by remove machine and user then set the desired settings with the LGPO editor MMC and grab the pol files that are created.