# Command to enable ELAM Policy

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know how enable ELAM (Early Launch Anti-Malware) policy-

1. Run  gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration>Administrative
   Templates>System>Early Launch Anti-Malware
3. Open "Boot-Start Driver Initialization Policy" and select "Enabled"

How to do this through batch file or simply through commands?

Thank you.

Comment: One observation: When i enable ELAM policy manually, it creates registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\EarlyLaunch" with "DriverLoadPolicy" having value 3. When i tried to do with on clean machine by creating above registry key the policy is not getting enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit windows Group Policy from Command line (CMD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341093/edit-windows-group-policy-from-command-line-cmd)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the reply  but its not duplicate. My problem is truly different. I know how to set GP using command. But its never getting updated for ELAM. Other GP works. Thanks.

Comment: This must be present in the question itself along with the information from your first comment. Please edit it accordingly as comments aren't meant for that.